# In Django, filter a query set for two datetimes being within one day

Tags: django

I have a Django model like:

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to find all `Person`s where `last_login` is within one day of `date_created`.

So far I have:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F

Person.objects.annotate(
    duration=F("last_login") - F("date_created")
).filter(duration__lte=timedelta(days=1))
```

But the tail end of the error when I do that is like:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1316, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, probably with that `timedelta(days=1)`.

Also (and I don't think this is the immediate error), I'm not sure if that query will take account of the fact that `last_login` could be `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F

Person.objects.filter(
    last_login__lte=F('date_created') + timedelta(days=1)
)
```

you can return records if `last_login` is `None`/`NULL` as well, with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F, Q

Person.objects.filter(
    Q(last_login__lte=F('date_created') + timedelta(days=1)) |
    Q(last_login=None)
)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I'm not sure why my attempt got that error, but this works.